# Overridding the label of "ok" button in <af:dialog> component in ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

In web layer of my project I am using ADF Faces component.In places I have used ADF popup element nested with dialog.

```
<af:popup id="myPopup" popupFetchListener="#{.....}">
        <af:dialog contentWidth="400" title="Dialog Title" contentHeight="100" closeIconVisible="true"
                   modal="true" type="okCancel" id="d3" 
                   dialogListener="#{mybean.myDialogListener}">
        </af:dialog>
 </af:popup>
```

In my backing bean I'm trapping the "ok"/"cancel" event with the help of `DialogEvent` class.

**I want to change the label of framework build "ok" button to some custom label based upon my project requirement**.If I add the desired label in message bundle how to reflect that in framework generated button?

Can anyone provide any clue for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the **Type**, **AffirmativeTextAndAccessKey** and **CancelTextAndAccessKey** properties of the dialog element.
To have the "ok" display "yes please" :

```
<af:popup id="myPopup" popupFetchListener="#{.....}">
    <af:dialog contentWidth="400" title="Dialog Title" contentHeight="100" closeIconVisible="true"
               modal="true" type="okCancel" id="d3" 
               dialogListener="#{mybean.myDialogListener}" type="yesNo" affirmativeTextAndAccessKey="yes please">
    </af:dialog>
```

Note : it will change the type of the response in your dialog listener from

```
dialogEvent.Outcome.ok
```

to

```
dialogEvent.Outcome.yes
```